# Filter date column for certain months

Tags: r, date, filter

I would like to turn a monthly time series into a quarterly one, by only keeping 4 values from the year. I have a date column in a dataframe as an integer in this monthly format:

```
192707
192708
192709
....
```

I have converted it to date format:

```
library(zoo)
df$date<-as.Date(as.yearmon(as.character(df$date), format = '%Y%m'), frac=1)
```

Next I was thinking to keep only 4 months of the year (Jan, Apr, Jul, Oct) with something like this, but I am not sure how to exactly do this:

```
df<-subset(df, month(df$date)==1 | month(df$date)==4 | 
            month(df$date)==7 | month(df$date)==10)
```

Is there a way to extract the month from the date column?

Comment: I'd recommend using a package. Specifically, see [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibbletime/vignettes/TT-02-changing-time-periods.html) from the [tibbletime](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibbletime/index.html) package.

Comment: You can get the month from a yearmon variable `ym` without converting it to Date using `cycle(ym)` .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tibbletime is very nice. cycle(ym) is also very nice!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are very close. Using the `months` function gives the full name of the month of the date, then using `month.name` we can get just the 4 months you want:

```
df <- df[months(df$date) %in% month.name[c(1,4,7,10)], ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be using `month number i.e. 1, 4, 7, 10` is as:

```
df[month(df$date) %% 3 == 1,]
```

In this one can avoid comparison on name. Hence it should be quick.

**Note:** I must mention here that OP has used `zoo` package.

Comment: Also, very nice!!! This will actually come in very handy for a few other things that I am trying to do, appreciate it!!!